# How to order sql server data by two different criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server

In a SQL server table, a column named SORT_ORDER_VALUE may contain either an int value or a null. All the rows having a value should be ordered by it while those rows which have a null value should be placed below the ones having a valid value, and be ordered among themselves alphabetically by the product_name. I have managed to place those without a value in the SORT_ORDER_VALUE column, to the bottom, by assigning a high value, 9999. But now I have to order those with a value of 9999 alphabetically. The following is the SQL I have created so far.

```
SELECT PRODUCT_NAME, PRICE, CASE WHEN SORT_ORDER_VALUE IS NULL THEN 9999 ELSE SORT_ORDER_VALUE 
END FROM PRODUCT ORDER BY  SORT_ORDER_VALUE
```

Comment: Assuming order by Product name just use PRODUCT_NAME ASC after the first ordering. like order by sort_order_value, product_name asc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
   PRODUCT_NAME, 
   PRICE, 
   CASE WHEN SORT_ORDER_VALUE IS NULL THEN 9999 ELSE SORT_ORDER_VALUE END 
FROM PRODUCT 
ORDER BY  
   CASE WHEN SORT_ORDER_VALUE IS NULL THEN 9999 ELSE SORT_ORDER_VALUE END, 
   PRODUCT_NAME
```

After `ORDER BY` you can have a comma separated list of columns on which to order.

If two rows have the same `SORT_ORDER_VALUE`, they will be sorted by the `PRODUCT_NAME`.

EDIT:

For the ORDER BY you can have a list of column names, or aliases, or repeat the complete expression. I prefer to re-use the complete expression, but you also could have written `ORDER BY 3,1` (give the position of the columns you want to sort by.

Comment: I have modified your code slightly as shown below.   SELECT 
   PRODUCT_NAME, 
   PRICE, 
   CASE WHEN SORT_ORDER_VALUE IS NULL THEN 9999 ELSE SORT_ORDER_VALUE END AS NEW_SORT_ORDER
FROM PRODUCT 
ORDER BY  
   NEW_SORT_ORDER, 
   PRODUCT_NAME

Answer (score 0):

This would also work:

```
SELECT 
   PRODUCT_NAME, 
   PRICE, 
   ISNULL(SORT_ORDER_VALUE, 9999) AS SORT_ORDER_VALUE
FROM PRODUCT 
ORDER BY  
   ISNULL(SORT_ORDER_VALUE, 9999), 
   PRODUCT_NAME
```